# Master/Detail with multiple detail pages with non-related content

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

How can I create a Master-Detail page application with multiple detail pages, which have nothing to do with each other? The content of the detail pages is completely different. Thanks.

Comment: a MasterDetail only has a single Detail page at any given time, but you can dynamically update the detail to contain different content.  Given the vagueness of your question its difficult to give a more specific answer.  Perhaps if you shared the relevant code and explained specifically what you're having problems doing?

Comment: @Jason Thank you for your answer. There is no code yet. I just need to be able to navigate from a left pane menu bar (it may have e.g. just 2 buttons) between 2 screens: one playing video and another displaying some data.

Comment: Button1 => MDPage.Detail = Page1;  Button2 => MDPage.Detail = Page2;  However in this scenario a TabbedPage might make more sense

Comment: @Jason Thank you! I will try this. Would you like to make this an answer, so that I might mark it as such if it works? Also, maybe you could refer me to some example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually, all you have to do is assign the Detail property based on whatever event you want to trigger the navigation

```
// assuming Page1 and Page2 are already instantiated
Button1 => MDPage.Detail = Page1; 

and ...

Button2 => MDPage.Detail = Page2;
```

note for this to work, your `Master` page will need to have a reference to the `MasterDetail` - you can either explicitly do this, or use `Application.Current.MainPage` to get the reference, or even use `MessagingCenter`